# numpy reshape implementation

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

My main focus will on [this page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html).

**First**, I don't understand the page. For the first parameter `shape`,

```
ndarray.reshape(shape, order='C')
```

why `this method on ndarray allows the elements of the shape parameter to be passed in as separate arguments`?

That is, why does this implementation allow `a.reshape(10, 11)`?

**Second**, I am wondering where the implementation on GitHub is? Searching the whole sentence "Returns an array containing the same data with a new shape" does not give me a correct link on GitHub. [My attempt](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Anumpy%2Fnumpy+%22Returns+an+array+containing+the+same+data+with+a+new+shape%22&type=code).

Thank you!

Comment: Typically numpy methods like th written in `c`, not python.  So the usual rules for a function `signature` aren't followed.  You could think of as accepting `*args`, and working with either a tuple or one or more  integers.  And the documentation isn't located with the code either.

Comment: Thanks! What does `th` mean in the comment above? "Typically numpy methods like th written in c, not python."

Comment: just a typo 'like this'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of being pedantic, here's some comparisons between using the function and the method versions.  The function version takes an initial object that it interprets as a array (or makes into an array).  The method already has the array object (`self`).

The function has a python signature, the method is compiled from `c` so can take some liberties in its signature (especially since it was written years ago before py3 and the current standards).

```
In [66]: x=np.arange(12)

In [67]: np.reshape(x,(3,4))
Out[67]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

The method can take either a tuple or numbers:

```
In [68]: x.reshape((3,4))
Out[68]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [69]: x.reshape(3,4)
Out[69]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

The function tries to interpret the 3rd argument as `order`:

```
In [70]: np.reshape(x,3,4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:57, in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 try:
---> 57     return bound(*args, **kwds)
     58 except TypeError:
     59     # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its
     60     # class, but its signature is not identical to that of NumPy's. This
   (...)
     64     # Call _wrapit from within the except clause to ensure a potential
     65     # exception has a traceback chain.

TypeError: order must be str, not int

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[70], line 1
----> 1 np.reshape(x,3,4)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in reshape(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:298, in reshape(a, newshape, order)
    198 @array_function_dispatch(_reshape_dispatcher)
    199 def reshape(a, newshape, order='C'):
    200     """
    201     Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data.
    202 
   (...)
    296            [5, 6]])
    297     """
--> 298     return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:66, in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     57     return bound(*args, **kwds)
     58 except TypeError:
     59     # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its
     60     # class, but its signature is not identical to that of NumPy's. This
   (...)
     64     # Call _wrapit from within the except clause to ensure a potential
     65     # exception has a traceback chain.
---> 66     return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:43, in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     41 except AttributeError:
     42     wrap = None
---> 43 result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
     44 if wrap:
     45     if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):

TypeError: order must be str, not int

In [71]: np.reshape(x,(3,4),'F')
Out[71]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
```

The method requires that the order be a keyword:

```
In [72]: x.reshape(3,4,'F')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[72], line 1
----> 1 x.reshape(3,4,'F')

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

In [73]: x.reshape(3,4,order='F')
Out[73]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
    
In [75]: x.reshape((3,4),'F')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[75], line 1
----> 1 x.reshape((3,4),'F')

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

In [76]: x.reshape((3,4),order='F')
Out[76]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
```

Compare these with the errors when the newshape is wrong.  Same error, but the function has the additional `wrapit` layering.

```
In [77]: x.reshape((3,5))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[77], line 1
----> 1 x.reshape((3,5))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12 into shape (3,5)

In [78]: np.reshape(x,(3,5))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[78], line 1
----> 1 np.reshape(x,(3,5))

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in reshape(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:298, in reshape(a, newshape, order)
    198 @array_function_dispatch(_reshape_dispatcher)
    199 def reshape(a, newshape, order='C'):
    200     """
    201     Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data.
    202 
   (...)
    296            [5, 6]])
    297     """
--> 298     return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:57, in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     54     return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 try:
---> 57     return bound(*args, **kwds)
     58 except TypeError:
     59     # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its
     60     # class, but its signature is not identical to that of NumPy's. This
   (...)
     64     # Call _wrapit from within the except clause to ensure a potential
     65     # exception has a traceback chain.
     66     return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12 into shape (3,5)
```

(these error tracebacks are long because the `ipython` `%xmode` is set to `verbose`.)

### edit

`np.random.rand` has this note:

```
rand(d0, d1, ..., dn)

Random values in a given shape.

.. note::
    This is a convenience function for users porting code from Matlab,
    and wraps `random_sample`. That function takes a
    tuple to specify the size of the output, which is consistent with
    other NumPy functions like `numpy.zeros` and `numpy.ones`.
```

While `numpy` consistently shows shape as tuple (even the 0d and 1d cases), there are functions/methods that accept it as individual numbers.  This note suggests this was an early feature of `numpy`, from the days when MATLAB still cast a long shaddow.

Of course in Python the `1,2,3` is just as much a tuple as `(1,2,3)`.  And in contexts like indexing the `()` are optional, e.g. `x[1,2,3]` is the same as `x[(1,2,3)]`.  Both are interpreted as `x.__getitem__((1,2,3))`.

Comment: Thanks! I think, in summary, the problem is that the signature of `numpy.ndarray.reshape` in page (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) is not perfectly correct. Thanks for the detailed explanations.